# How do I use CoreData to manage a prebuilt SQL database?

Tags: core-data

I'm working on a simple app that helps you track calories, carbs, proteins etc.
You start out with a basic list of foods and their values and you can add you own as well.

For example:
an apple has x cals, y carbs, z proteins etc.
Steak has 3x cals, 3y carbs, 3z proteins etc.
and so on...

I would prefer that when the app loads for the first time it doesn't need to go through a process of Core Data building the initial database of foods from a pList or SQL file.

Is there a way to pre-build a database with CoreData so that the user's iPhone doesn't have to do that work?

Objective C is my first language and I've never learned SQL. All the examples I've worked on for CoreData involved creating a database by interacting with the user interface. There must be a way to manage a prebuilt database. Is there terminology to distinguish between the two types of databases (the one created at Runtime and the one created before runtime)?

Thanks.

-A

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, currently you have a data dump that you parse during the first run of your app, and put into Core Data. This takes some time, and you'd instead like to ship your app with this information preloaded (negating the need to parse it).

If that's the case, there is a reasonable tutorial on pre-loading Core Data here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

Note that you will need to know some SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can include a pre-built database into your application bundle and upload it to AppStore. However since your AppBundle has checksums and the device checks these checksums to make sure the applications wasn't modified – you can't make modifications to your database in this form.

So the solution is to include the pre-built database into your application bundle, and when the user downloads your application and starts it the first time, you duplicate your pre-built database into the applications Documents or Applications Support folder where you are allowed to change it.

Hope this helps.